# property_exists method not hitting

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, api

So I came up with this code:

```
    public function duplicateSelectedAd($request)
{
    $setData = [];
    $newAd = $request[0];
    foreach($newAd as $key=>$value) {
        if(property_exists(AdFields::class, strtoupper($key))){
            $setData[AdFields::strtoupper($key)] = array_get($request[0], $value);
        }
    }
    $ad = new Ad(null, 'act_'.$newAd['account_id']);
    $ad->setData($setData)->create();
}
```

It checks through all the indexes of a returned array and is supposed to duplicate them into a new ad.  This is all via the facebook API.  Here is the addsfield class:

```
class AdFields extends AbstractEnum {

  const ACCOUNT_ID = 'account_id';
  const AD_REVIEW_FEEDBACK = 'ad_review_feedback';
  const ADLABELS = 'adlabels';
  const ADSET = 'adset';
  const ADSET_ID = 'adset_id';
  const BID_AMOUNT = 'bid_amount';
  const BID_INFO = 'bid_info';
  const BID_TYPE = 'bid_type';
  const CAMPAIGN = 'campaign';
  const CAMPAIGN_ID = 'campaign_id';
  const CONFIGURED_STATUS = 'configured_status';
  const CONVERSION_SPECS = 'conversion_specs';
  const CREATED_TIME = 'created_time';
  const CREATIVE = 'creative';
  const EFFECTIVE_STATUS = 'effective_status';
  const ID = 'id';
  const LAST_UPDATED_BY_APP_ID = 'last_updated_by_app_id';
  const NAME = 'name';
  const RECOMMENDATIONS = 'recommendations';
  const SOURCE_AD = 'source_ad';
  const SOURCE_AD_ID = 'source_ad_id';
  const STATUS = 'status';
  const TRACKING_SPECS = 'tracking_specs';
  const UPDATED_TIME = 'updated_time';
  const ADSET_SPEC = 'adset_spec';
  const DATE_FORMAT = 'date_format';
  const DISPLAY_SEQUENCE = 'display_sequence';
  const EXECUTION_OPTIONS = 'execution_options';
  const FILENAME = 'filename';

  public function getFieldTypes() {
    return array(
      'account_id' => 'string',
      'ad_review_feedback' => 'AdgroupReviewFeedback',
      'adlabels' => 'list<AdLabel>',
      'adset' => 'AdSet',
      'adset_id' => 'string',
      'bid_amount' => 'int',
      'bid_info' => 'map<string, unsigned int>',
      'bid_type' => 'BidType',
      'campaign' => 'Campaign',
      'campaign_id' => 'string',
      'configured_status' => 'ConfiguredStatus',
      'conversion_specs' => 'list<ConversionActionQuery>',
      'created_time' => 'datetime',
      'creative' => 'AdCreative',
      'effective_status' => 'EffectiveStatus',
      'id' => 'string',
      'last_updated_by_app_id' => 'string',
      'name' => 'string',
      'recommendations' => 'list<AdRecommendation>',
      'source_ad' => 'Ad',
      'source_ad_id' => 'string',
      'status' => 'Status',
      'tracking_specs' => 'list<ConversionActionQuery>',
      'updated_time' => 'datetime',
      'adset_spec' => 'AdSet',
      'date_format' => 'string',
      'display_sequence' => 'unsigned int',
      'execution_options' => 'list<ExecutionOptions>',
      'filename' => 'file',
    );
  }
}
```

If I return $newAd before the loop I get all of the adfields options with either values or null and so I know I'm bringing it in, right.  I just don't know why it's not hitting that if statement.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are constants not properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit dirty but you can concatenate the class and constant name as a defined argument to check if it exists:

```
$constant = AdFields::class . '::' . strtoupper($key);
defined($constant);
```

`AdFields::strtoupper($key)` won't work as you expect it.  This is going to try to call a static method named strtoupper on the AdFields class.  When retrieving dynamic constants, you'll need to use the constant method with the same concatenated string:

```
constant($constant)
```

Comment: Dirty but works, thanks.  I'm going to look into class reflection a bit more too.  Much appreciated.